# How to keep remote processes from ending when disconnected

Tags: macos, ssh, raspberry-pi, osx-mavericks

I am trying to run a Minecraft server on a Raspberry Pi.

I have an SSH connection open in the terminal on my MacBook Pro running OS X Mavericks.

I started the minecraft server from this, however, I want to be able to close the terminal and shut down my Mac and still have the minecraft server running.

Thank you for your time. Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: You need to start the process in the background: Try `nohup minecraft-server-command &`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use tmux or screen!

the above are software applications that can be used to multiplex several virtual consoles, allowing a user to access multiple separate terminal sessions inside a single terminal.

That's how you can use tmux to achieve what you are looking for:

- Install `tmux` (in a MAC, tmux does not come installed by default)
- start tmux by typing `tmux`
- call the process you want to survive a log off inside the tmux session
- detach the tmux session by typing Ctrl-B and then D

You can now disconnect from the remote machine and when you connect back again you can use `tmux attach` to attach to your tmux session and resume your work.

PS: You can install tmux by downloading the source and building it yourself:

- https://blogs.oracle.com/unixben/entry/install_tmux_on_mac_os
- http://blog.bigappleinsider.com/content/installing-tmux-mac-os-x

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately when I type "tmux" in the terminal  I get the message "-bash: tmux: command not found" indicating it is not installed. Do you know where I can install it?

Comment: Thanks but I'm on Mac, not Linux. I get a "sudo: apt-get: command not found" error.